# Monitor tornado AsyncHTTPClient queue when max_clients is reached

Tags: python, python-2.7, tornado

In a large scale tornado application we are using shared `AsyncHTTPClient` for our outgoing requests with a pre-set max_clients.

```
http_client = tornado.httpclient.AsyncHTTPClient(max_clients=100)

class SomeHandler(tornado.web.RequestHandler):

    @tornado.gen.coroutine
    def get(self, *args, **kwargs):
        response = yield tornado.gen.Task(http_client.fetch, <some_url>, method='GET')
        ...
```

What i would like to ask, is there a way to see at any given time, if the `max_clients` treshold had been reached and what is the count of the requests in the queue, to help us scaling it up if needed?

Answer (score 1):

There is currently no supported way to do this. You could peek at implementation details of the AsyncHTTPClient implementation (with no guarantees about future compatibility), or wrap the AsyncHTTPClient object with something that keeps a count of pending fetches.

Comment: Thank you @ben-darnell . I found a workaround for now by monitoring the `time_info.queue` of the response objects (we're using CurlAsyncHTTPClient)